# .NET Core 3.1 AWS Lambda + API Gateway no internet access

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

When I try Lambda ASP.NET Core Web API template it works as expected and lambda has internet access.

Following code works as expected:

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

[HttpGet]
public string Get() {   
    return client.GetStringAsync("http://www.google.com").Result;        
}
```

When I try Lambda Empty Function template similar code doesn't work and lambda times out. If I remove client.GetStringAsync lambda works and returns a response.

This doesn't work:

```
 public class Function {
        private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        public APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse FunctionHandler(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context) {                         
            var response = client.GetStringAsync("http://www.google.com").Result;                                  
            return new APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Body = response,
                Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                    { "Content-Type", "application/json" },
                    { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" }
                }
            };                            
        }
    }
```

Infrastructure remains the same. I only change a handler for the aws_lambda_function resource in Terraform.

Why Lambda Empty Function template doesn't have internet access?

Comment: did you put it into a vpc?

Comment: @DanielA.White: Yes Lambda is in a VPC and there's a NAT gateway that gives it access to the internet. Also, I've tested the infrastructure with nodejs lambda and it had access to the internet.

Comment: You could be deadlocking by using Result not await

Comment: @DanielA.White: You are correct. I changed the handler function to be async, added await and it works. Thank you.